# Getting all descendants of json request

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get just name field using this query. But it gives me all data from json including school, class, ect.
Is there a way to write this so i just get value of names like:

john, ken, ...

```
var names = obj.Descendants()
                        .OfType<JProperty>()
                        .Where(p => p.Name == "name").Values().Distinct().ToList();
```

Jason string:

```
{"items":[{"id":404,"name":"Ken":{"id":215,"neighbourhood":"Mississauga"}]
    ,{"id":407,"name":"John":{"id":215,"neighbourhood":"Toronto"}]
    ,...
```

It is returning me all the value under id:404 i just want name that is Ken, John

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you add a [mcve] showing the JSON you want to query, and the result you want?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed, according to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and http://jsonlint.com/.  Can you provide an actual example of the JSON you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

At first your json has some error to validate. The inner object has not any key!
Why you don't use jquery each structure?

```
var arr = [];
$.each(jsonObj.items, function(ind, val){
    arr[ind] = val.name;
});
```